# regexp of a number with 11 digits beginning with 09

Tags: mysql, regex

I want a simple regex to match numbers like this

```
09876765456
or 
09253647586
```

to use in mysql select syntax like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table` 
WHERE  `number` REGEXP 'regex'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This is pretty simple. Did you even try anything first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table` 
WHERE  `number` REGEXP '^09\d{9}$'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do that:

```
^09\d{9}$
```

The text `09` followed by 9 digits. The `^` and `$` anchor the match to the start and end of the string.